# Use visual Studio designer with custom build tool

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have a winforms application and want to create a class hierarchy like:

```
MyForm : MyOtherNonAbstractForm : System.Windows.Form
```

As I'm using a custom build tool which is not integrated with VS, I'm unable to view MyForm in the Designer (as I'm unable to build inside VS).

Is there a workaround for having a Designer-View for MyForm without building the solution in VS? I could add the resulting DLL as a reference, but this doesn't seem like a good workaround ...

Comment: the Visual Studio designer does not support abstract classes. Regardless how they are compiled. BTW doing too much inheritance in the UI level seems like a hack.

Comment: If "MyAbstractForm" would be non-abstract (which makes obviously no sense), then the designer would work. Is there a way to reach this scenario?
I want to add some default behavior to a form (e.g. actions on helpRequested etc), I can't see any other way without code duplication.